# Show that such a finite plane graph doesn't exist

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

Show that there is no finite plane graph whose every face is a hexagon and each two neighboring faces have exactly one edge in common.

So this is one of the questions I am asked to solve for my discrete math 2 class. I believe I have to solve this using the concept of dual planar graph but I might be wrong

Comment: Your idea of using dual planar graphs sounds promising. For contradiction suppose such a planar graph existed, what would its dual look like? And why is this impossible?

Comment: So i think it would be a graph having a K3,3 form ? I am not exactly sure how to prove it completely

Comment: In that case I will post an answer.

Comment: Thank you @79037662

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For contradiction suppose there exists a graph $G$ which is planar, and whose every face is a hexagon and each two neighboring faces have exactly one edge in common.

The dual of $G$ (call it $G'$) is a planar graph.

Every face of $G$ is adjacent to exactly 6 other faces by construction, so every vertex of $G'$ has degree 6.

There is a theorem that for all planar graphs with 3 or more vertices, $e\leq3v-6$ where $e$ is the number of edges and $v$ is the number of vertices. By handshake lemma, $G'$ has $3v$ edges since all its vertices have degree 6. This is a contradiction so $G$ cannot exist.